# Strange behaviour with border-image CSS

Tags: html, css, image, border

I have an image that I would like to use as div's border and background. The below code (and [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qazLuyxh/)) produces undesirable white background inside the div despite using `background: transparent !important;` or `background: none !important;` (I tried both).

Here's the image I'm using:

[image]

Here's the effect I'm getting:

[image]

Here's the effect I want:

[image]

Strangely, I can achieve the desired effect by opening Web Inspector in Chrome and toggling the `border-image` property after page render. Simply turning the `border-image` off and back on, I get the result I want:

[image]

**HTML**

```
<div>test</div>
```

**CSS**

```
div {
    -webkit-border-image: url(http://img.ctrlv.in/img/14/10/28/544fc2d75c818.png) 30 30 round; /* Safari 3.1-5 */
    -o-border-image: url(http://img.ctrlv.in/img/14/10/28/544fc2d75c818.png) 30 30 round; /* Opera 11-12.1 */
    border-image: url(http://img.ctrlv.in/img/14/10/28/544fc2d75c818.png) 30 30 round;
}
```

So if the browser can render it, why can't I write it? :) Any help/suggestions would be great.

**Please note** I have already tried setting the image to be the div's `background-image` instead of `border-image` and that did not produce desired results either (scaling the image to prevent the border from getting cut off was simply too much guess work since the textual contents of the div are dynamic).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're lacking the `fill` keyword: the [standard](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-backgrounds/#the-border-image-slice) says:

> The ‘fill’ keyword, if present, causes the middle part of the
>   border-image to be preserved. (By default it is discarded, i.e.,
>   treated as empty.)

See [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qazLuyxh/17/): writing `30 30 fill` seems to solve your issue.

Comment: Thank you kindly for the answer as well as the reminder to double check the spec! :)

Comment: I know that sometimes the specs can be scary, but sometimes they solve your problem :)

Answer (score 0):

Does something like this work for you? http://jsfiddle.net/qazLuyxh/9/

```
div {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 40px;
    width: 520px;
    height: 320px;
    background: url(http://img.ctrlv.in/img/14/10/28/544fc2d75c818.png) no-repeat;
    color: #FFB9B9;
    font: bold 24px/41px'fontname', Helvetica, sans-serif !important;
    background-size: 100%;
}
```

Comment: The problem with the background-image route is some of the border at the bottom gets cut off. The dimensions in the fiddle were for demonstrational purposes only. The actual height will be fluid due to the contents.

Answer (score 0):

[JSFiddle - Click Here](http://jsfiddle.net/9qyLb6fj/)

Maybe this will help you. Just shooting in the dark.

```
#block {
background-image: url("http://img.ctrlv.in/img/14/10/28/544fc2d75c818.png");
height: 100%;
width: 450px;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
}


#block .blocktext {
padding: 50px;
}
```